# Grabbing external json to store into database

Tags: php, json

I need to grab about 70K small json files to store into a db. The json file names are numbered from 1-70,000. What would be the best way to grab them all?

This is how the files are structured.

```
domain.com/go.php?file=user/stats.json&id=1
domain.com/go.php?file=user/stats.json&id=2
domain.com/go.php?file=user/stats.json&id=3
domain.com/go.php?file=user/stats.json&id=4
```

etc

Comment: Are you wanting to do this with linux command line tools? Python? C++? Do you just want to download them, or do you want to add them to the database as well? Please add more information to your question and add relevant tags to indicate the language you're using/want to use.

Comment: I would like to download them atm, but will need to add them to a database eventually. I am not sure what DB will fit best for the task yet, but they will be accessed through php. The db is something I have yet to research on what would be best. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple bash one-liner to download all the files would be:

```sh
for i in $(seq 1 70000); do wget "domain.com/go.php?file=user/stats.json&id=${i}" -o "${i}.json"; done
```

---

If you require downloading them using PHP then something like this should work (I don't use PHP, so I'm not 100% sure though: corrections welcome):

```php
for ($x = 1; $x <= 70000; $x++) {
    file_put_contents("{$i}.json", fopen("domain.com/go.php?file=user/stats.json&id={$i}", 'r'));
}
```

You could later skip the step of storing them locally by writing the contents of the remote JSON file (from `fopen`) to the DB directly, rather than to a file first.

Comment: Awesome, don't know why I didn't think of a bash script it is working perfectly. I am trying the php approach also just to see how it would work with so many files, but wasn't getting anything. I lowered the 70000 number to 50 to test, and it would load for a few seconds, but nothing. I'm interested in the part about storing to a db directly, however I have no idea what db I should be using yet and the easiest way to approach this. Have any recommendations? Thank you!

Comment: @stoggafu I haven't tested the PHP approach I'm afraid. It'll probably be downloading the files to the root folder of your website, make sure you've searched around a bit. About which database to use, that's not on-topic for StackOverflow (asking for external resources). Just pick one and run with it, it won't make any difference in the long run.